# How to configure Dynamic WebAPI in AspNetCore

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

How can I configure the dynamic WebAPI in aspnetcore version of abp?

```
Configuration.Modules.AbpWebApi()
```

The method `AbpWebApi` doesn't exists.

Do I need to install an extra nuget package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's different for AspNet Core.
See documentation: https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/AspNet-Core#application-services-as-controllers

Answer (score 1):

in **PreInitialize** method of your abp module add this line;

> Configuration.Modules.AbpAspNetCore().CreateControllersForAppServices(typeof(MyApplicationModule).Assembly,
>   moduleName: 'app', useConventionalHttpVerbs: true);

Answer (score 0):

I spend about 4 hours trying to find AbpAspNetCore() method. Finally I came up with decorating methods and classes with [RemoteService(isEnabled:false)] attribute

Answer (score 0):

Ive just run into the same thing.

Ive not got everything up and running however there seems to be a number of nuget packages to install which isnt made particulary clear in the help documentation.

I have just installed the "AbpAspNetCore" package to the application layer

The same is true for the .Net version except the package name is "Abp.Web.Api"

Installing the required package will enable to to access the AbpAspNetCore method

Comment: Are you using the template? If you are, then it is already installed and done for you in Web.Core project.

Comment: After messing about for ages I realised it it worked on any action without a configuration line in the module . Do you know how I stop the action being available through the API? So my whole application interface isn't exposed

Comment: Use `RemoteService` attribute as described in another answer.